# How to specify a month in cell A1 and have all the dates that fall in that month appear automatically in row B?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a question about Excel. I am using Excel 2010 and I want to be able to create a table that will auto populate the dates within the month that is specified in cell eg **A1** into a row in **B** for example.

---

**EXAMPLE**

Select Month Cell = October **(A1)**

**(Row B)**

All

The

Days

In

October

In

A

List

Automatically

---

I want to be able to select any month in the list and it should populate the correct amount of days, not sure if it is possible but worth an ask!

Alex

Comment: By "all the dates", do you mean a list of the numbers 1 through 28, 29, 30, or 31 as appropriate for that month, or more information about each date, or pull dates with entries from a calendar somewhere?  Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a number instead of the name of the month, in cells B1 - B31 you can do:

```
=IF(MONTH(DATE(2014,$A$1,ROW()))=$A$1,DATE(2014,$A$1,ROW()),"")
```

You can use a number and just use custom formatting ("mmmm") to make it still appear as the month name.